Display numpy 2D array as an RGBImage
I want to display an RGBColor bitmap as an image
I have several functions that fill the bitmap.
also at some point I will add an alpha channel.
I saw similar questions but none of them worked for me.
display an rgb matrix image in python
I have an RGBColor class defined as
class RGBColor:
    bytes = np.zeros(3, dtype=np.ubyte)

    # RGBColor.__new__
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().__new__(cls)
    
    # RGBColor.__init__
    def __init__(self, r: int, g: int, b: int) -> None:
        self.bytes[0] = r
        self.bytes[1] = g
        self.bytes[2] = b

and a Bitmap defined as
class Bitmap:
    # Point.__new__
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().__new__(cls)

    # Point.__init__
    def __init__(self, rows: int, cols: int, backColor: RGBColor) -> None:
        self.bits = np.empty( (rows,cols), dtype=RGBColor)
        for r in range(rows):
            for c in range(cols):
                self.bits[r][c] = backColor

and my attempt at displaying this is
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    def show(self, bitmap: Bitmap):
        plt.imshow(bitmap.bits)
        plt.show()

The error I get is

File
"C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line
706, in set_data
raise TypeError("Image data of dtype {} cannot be converted to "
TypeError: Image data of dtype object cannot be converted to float


You need to imshow a RGBA numpy array convertible to float, of shape (rows, cols, 4). Actually, you might not need any of your classes. You can work directly with an array such as obtained from np.random.randint(0, 256, (32, 32, 4), dtype=np.ubyte).

You created an array of RGBColor objects. imshow can only handle int or float arrays, so you'd need a function to convert your object array to an int or float array. Here is an example of such a function (can certainly be optimized):
def to_numpy(self):
    return np.array([b.bytes.tolist() for b in self.bits.flat], dtype=np.ubyte).reshape(self.bits.shape + (3,))

Then you can call it like
bitmap = Bitmap(3, 2, RGBColor(100, 50, 200))
plt.imshow(bitmap.to_numpy())


